# When to use Value Formatter and when to use Value Resolver

Tags: automapper

I am still confused of when to use Value Formatter versus Value Resolver in automapper.

Say I have a nullable DateTime that I want to make into a specific date format(so the end result would be a string). Should I use Formatter in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and chose Value Resolver based upon documentation from the author himself that Value Formatter is likely a design mistake:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-formatters

However, that same author provided a response to what to use when here:

[Why does AutoMapper have an IValueFormatter when it has a seemingly much more powerful ValueResolver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170485/why-does-automapper-have-an-ivalueformatter-when-it-has-a-seemingly-much-more-po)